# Htaccess how to replace special sequence of characters

Tags: .htaccess

Here I got such url

```
http://minecraftstorage/add
```

And this rule

```
RewriteRule ^add/? add.php [L]
```

But that rule affects not only **add** string which is in URL, but also **additionals** string which is in the path to Bootstrap css. 
So how can I make it to work only for **add** and not for **additionals**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `RewriteRule ^add/?$ add.php [L]`

$ denotes the end of a regex (regex = regular expression) test string.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.